The inner product of $xf'(x)$ and $g(x)$, $\int x f'(x) g(x)$, always vanishes if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are probability distribution functions
Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be probability distribution functions defined in the interval $[a,b]$, and assume that the mean of the distribution $g$ exists, i.e. $\int_a^b x g(x) = \mu_g$, and the derivative of $f(x)$, $f'(x)$ is well defined.
Then, it seems that the inner product of $xf'(x)$ and $g(x)$, $\int_a^b x f'(x) g(x)$, always vanishes.
Using integration by parts $u = f'(x)$ and $dv = x g(x) dx$, with $du = f''(x) dx$ and $v = \int_a^b x g(x) dx = \mu_g$
So
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_a^b x f'(x) g(x) dx &= \left[\left(\int_a^b x g(x) dx\right) f'(x)\right]_a^b - \int_a^b \left(\int_a^b x g(x) dx\right) f''(x) dx\\
&= \left[\mu_g f'(x)\right]_a^b - \int_a^b \mu_g f''(x) dx\\
&= \mu_x\left( f' |_{a}^{b} - \int_{a}^{b} f''(x) dx  \right) \\
&= \mu_x\left( f' |_{a}^{b} - f' |_{a}^{b}  \right) =0 &&(??)
\end{aligned}$$
This does not seem to make much sense. Taking $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ to be the PDFs of triangular distributions from $0 to 1$, for instance, we have:
$$\begin{aligned}
f(x) = g(x) &= 2x \\
f'(x)  &= 2 \\
\int_0^1 x f'(x) g(x) dx &= \int_0^1 x (2) (2x) dx = 4  \int_0^1 x^2 dx = \frac{4}{3} x^3 |_0^1 = \frac{4}{3} \neq 0
\end{aligned}$$
However, I cannot see the mistake in either reasoning, what went wrong?

The intergal need not be $0$. Check you integration by parts.  I cannot really understand how you got $0$.

$v(x) = \int_a^x$, not $\int_a^b$.

I think that taking $\int_a^b$ instead of  was the mistake indeed, thanks @HansLundmark
